# Trying to put an image in my question and cannot

Tags: support, images

I have a photo which I can't seem to paste into here using the image icon in the editing menu. I'm not sure why that is.
I have seen someone else do that here. Before I proceed I need to solve this issue.
Every time I click that icon an upload window appears telling me my image is too large even though I had not even selected an image to upload yet and when I do move an image into the upload window it prompts me to leave the page and if I say yes, it just shows the image in a webpage.
Any pointers here?

Comment: Does this help: [Image uploads not working on Chrome](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/292019/307988) (try disabling any extensions you have active)

Comment: yes I had that norton extension. Well done @Cai. Thankyou.